# Dataset of large graphs for classifiction

Tags: machine-learning, network-structure, big-data

I want to evaluate a graph kernel designed for **large graphs** (> 10^6 nodes). Hence, I'm looking for suitable graph data sets, i.e., a set of (huge) graphs and corresponding classes.

Any ideas?

Comment: What type of graphs are you looking for? Would twitter data help?

Comment: @sheß: Both directed and undirected graphs are fine. Each graph should belong to a class so I can perform classification. Could you please elaborate on the twitter data.

Answer (score 2):

Try [Stanford Large Network Dataset Collection](https://snap.stanford.edu/data/#web)

https://snap.stanford.edu/data/egonets-Facebook.html[[image: is facebook and has undirected graphs]

[Directed graphs twitter](https://snap.stanford.edu/data/egonets-Twitter.html)
is listed undirected and directed graphs.

Hope it answer your question.

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of SNAP. Unfortunately, most of the datasets consist of a single large graph.

Comment: Than will be need to build on your own. Check databricks graphX https://databricks-training.s3.amazonaws.com/graph-analytics-with-graphx.html

Comment: @Christopher. how large do you need?

Comment: @sb709: Let's say 100 graphs for each class (two classes are sufficient), each graph should have at least 10^6 nodes.